# Mapping 3 entities through a common bridge table using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to model the fact that a team needs multiple skills to function.
Many persons can have a certain skill.
A person has many skills.
A person can be part of many teams.

I use Hibernate to model this scenario.
I started building with two entities, team and skill, and used @ManyToMany annotation to link these dependencies. Trying to add the third entity, person, is where it got difficult. I don't understand how I should build this model and would greatly appreciate any help.

I don't have much experience using Hibernate so this is a challenge.

I have searched for information and most examples I found was about two connected entities and I haven't been able to scale those examples to include a third entity.

These are my entities:

```
package com.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Person> persons;
}



package com.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Skill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String knowHow;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Team> teams;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Person> persons;
}



package com.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Set<Team> teams;
    private Set<Skill> skills;
}
```

These are my repositories:

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.entity.Competence;
import com.example.entity.Team;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long> {
    List<Competence> findDistinctByKnowHow(String name);
}



package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.entity.Competence;
import com.example.entity.Skill;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface SkillRepository extends CrudRepository<Skill, Long> {

    List<Competence> findDistinctByKnowHow(String knowHow);

}



package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.entity.Competence;
import com.example.entity.Person;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Competence> findDistinctByPerson(String name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create an entity that solely exists as a bridge entity. That way you can add three different 1-to-many relationsships between your "real" entities and your bridge entity. That way you should be able to handle the threeway many-to-many relationship.

You will probably have to handle the data in the bridge entity "manually" though.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are not able to do that. This model contains logical inconsistency and can lead to contradictions. Imagine that you have a **TeamA** which contains 2 members (**PersonA**, **PersonB**). **PersonA** contains **SkillA** and **PersonB** contains **SkillB**. That means that **TeamA** should contain 2 skills (**SkillA** and **SkillB**). However, your model should allow for putting skills on team level independently of members. What would happen then if you'd put only **SkillA** on **skills** property of **TeamA**?

I think you should leave many-to-many relationship between

- **Person** and **Skill**
- **Team** and **Person**

The **skills** property on **Team** level should be derived.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question has merit.

Using a common bridge table between the three entities allows for a row level security by design assuming a team can only see the competencies they add themselves.

Take the example of a consultant working with VB in one team. She truly dislikes VB and does not want her other team to know that she has this skill.

Team A can know Person A has the Skill VB.
Team B should not know that Person A has the Skill VB.

I would have added this as a comment but I lack the necessary reputation =/